# Are django session variables secure?

Tags: python, django, session, oauth-2.0

I am creating an app for use in our organization that will login users based on their Office 365 credentials using OAuth2.0. I am fetching an access token that I will store in a session variable. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
@never_cache
def authorization(request):
    microsoft = OAuth2Session(client_id,scope=scope,redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
    token = ""
    try:
        users = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me' ##msgraph query url- 
        ##This query is purelyjust used to 
        ##authenticate user!
        token = microsoft.fetch_token(token_url,client_secret=client_secret,code=request.GET.get('code', '')) ##Code is the authorization code present
        ##in request URL
        header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']}
        response = requests.get(url = users, headers = header)

        if int(response.status_code) != 200: ##if status code is not 200, then authentication failed. Redirect to login.
            print ('Not validated. Return to login.')
            request.session.flush()
            return redirect('http://localhost:8000/login')
    except Exception as e:
        print ('User not does not have authentication rights')
        request.session.flush()
        return redirect('http://localhost:8000/login')

    request.session['oauth_state'] = 'authorized'
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost:8000/search')
    return response
```

I am then using this to check if 'oauth_state' is set to 'authorized'. However, I may change this so that the token is used to query the MS Graph API in each function in order to check if the user has proper permissions or not. Here's an example of what I am doing:

```
def search(request):
        try:
            if (str(request.session['oauth_state']) != 'authorized'):
                print ('Not authorized')
                request.session.flush()
                return redirect('http://localhost:8000/login')
        except Exception as e:
            print ('Not authorized')
            request.session.flush()
            return redirect('http://localhost:8000/login')
    <rest of code>
```

How insecure is this? Should I possibly be passing in the token to the response header? Or should I get rid of this method, and use django's standard auth and login system? I really appreciated the benefits of OAuth2.0, but if this method compromises our security, I might scrap it.

Comment: The main problem is you are comparing 2 session variables to each other, Since after you oauth they are set to the same value, under what circumstance will they not be the same value? (if stored in cookie, what stops a client from just making sure  they give you 2 identical values). Session variables share the same persistence in the same storage. What you need is to store one value that the client will present and another value that persists across sessions on the server to compare.

Comment: Agreed. I will change that. But you do not think there is a problem with storing session variables themselves? That's the main issue I'm concerned with.

Comment: one of the values will _have_ to be a "session variable" otherwise you wouldn't be able to stay logged in...

Comment: Couldn't I pass the token into the response header? Or I thought I could use django's auth system to avoid messing with session variables

Comment: Sorry, not following, not sure how putting oauth token into response header helps you, since it's the browser that gets the response....

Comment: Nevermind, then. Basically, I would just like to know if storing an access token in a session variable is secure.

Comment: It would depend on what security you're looking for. Only risk revolves around sessions stored in cookies when using `SESSION_ENGINE = django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies` which are crypto signed that invalidates the cookie variable if not modified by django (but client can read the its oauth token). But for all session backends, session ID is stored in cookie.